# Lower bound on $E(X^3)$ or: Is $Cov(X,X^2)\geq 0$ for $X\geq 0$

Tags: variance, expected-value, linear-algebra, bounds

I'm wondering if for a *non-negative* random variable $X\geq 0$ there is a lower bound on $E(X^3)$, such as for example for $E(X^2)$ $$E(X^2)\geq E(X)^2$$, which follows from $var(X)\geq0$.

I tried decomposing:$$E(X^3)=E(X^2X)=E(X^2)\cdot E(X) + COV(X^2,X)$$

Using the statement above I can bound the first part below by $E(X)^3$. But I'm not sure if the covariance term can be bound..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Clearly Cov$(X^2,X)$ can be negative.

Comment: also in the case of non-negative X?

Comment: If $X\geq 0$ is the situation (I see it's in your title now), can you also edit it into the body of your question as well?  ... Clearly if $X$ is non-negative the covariance can't be negative.

Comment: great, thanks! So in this case $E(X^3)\geq E(X)^3$ holds, right? Also, do you have any hint on how to show the nonnegativity of the covariance?

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^3$ is convex on $x \geq 0$, the result follows from Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 4):

So as Chris pointed out in the above comment 
$$ E(X^3) \geq E(X)^3$$ follows directly from **Jensen's inequality** since $f(x)=x^3$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$